# Center and scale a graph group in SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a list of point that represent a graph contained in a `svg:group`.
My html is currently:

```
<svg id="parent">
    <g id="child">
        <!-- graph list of points here -->
    </g>
</svg>
```

Because the points are computed on user input, they can be far or not from each other but it will always be a point at the origin (0,0).
I would like to center and scale the `child` group in its parent in order to see all the points of the graph.
I tried to used `transform` on `child` and it center the origin point but not the whole graph.

Can someone explain me how to do? I also use `d3.js` to place the points.

Comment: you need to use the domain and scale while drawing the graph. Follow https://www.dashingd3js.com/table-of-contents to learn d3js it will manage ur scale and other things

Comment: @murli2308 hi, thanks for your answer, can you tell me please if it is better to use `d3.scale/domain` each time I draw a point or there is a way to scale and domain directly the axes and d3.js will do the job when I ask it to draw?

Comment: domain depends on data you provide to draw the graph. It is always better to use scale and domain each time

Comment: @murli2308 Thanks for your time. I achieved what I wanted using d3.scale.linear() https://www.dashingd3js.com/d3js-scales